# How to get results from event handler of window.external.Notify("someText") i.e. WebBrowser.ScriptNotify Event back to JS?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8

I am using window.external.Notify("someText") in my `WP8 HTML5 App`

```
function func() 
{ 
   window.external.Notify("clearTextBox"); 
}
```

I have written event handler for ScriptNotify

```
private void BrowserScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
        //Do your business here
}
```

My XAML has:

`<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Loaded="Browser_Loaded"
                          IsScriptEnabled="true"
                            ScriptNotify="BrowserScriptNotify"
                          NavigationFailed="Browser_NavigationFailed" />`

Everything works fine but how to get results from event handler back to JS? Is calling a JS function at last line of event handler is the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you're crossing the boundary between languages you can't use return values.
The only way to share results is to make another call back in the other direction.

Comment: It's no use in the OP case but you can get a result from `WebBrowser.InvokeScript` which returns the result of a JS fn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402855(v=vs.105).aspx.

Comment: On the other hand, `window.external.GetFoo()` can return `foo` as either a string or a JSON object string.